# What dependencies does the Intel C/C++ compiler have against Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, intel

I want to give the Intel C and C++ compilers a shot but... I intend to totally avoid Visual Studio (unless there's a runtime dependency.)  My machine already has several different versions of the VS runtime as it cannot be avoided.

Does Intel state anywhere what the dependencies are?  I've seen notes almost everywhere but from Intel that state what they need from Visual Studio so I'm not interested in anecdotals here.

Comment: Did you try using the intel compiler yet?

Comment: @stefan Not yet.  I'm not going to spend the money if I have to buy VS as well, at least not right now.

Comment: I would seriously doubt that it has such a dependency. That would require a cooperation between two closed-source projects from two different companies. Additionally, you can try the 30-day free trial now..

Comment: @stefan: The Intel compiler officially claims to require Visual Studio but gives no reason why.  I'm looking for the why and hoping to avoid VS.

Comment: Have you read the same page as I did? http://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers/ Under "integration" it says it integrates into VS, but that doesn't mean it depends on it.

Comment: @stefan: The installer checks for Visual Studio.

Comment: While this is a good question for Stackoverflow, especially since it will give any answer a wide audience, have you also asked Intel?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: No I have not.  Since they've made it clear they want Visual Studio involved, the answer will likely be less than useful and time consuming to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

From the release notes for Intel C++ Composer XE for Windows:

```
To use the Microsoft Visual Studio development environment or command-line tools to
build IA-32 or Intel® 64 architecture applications, one of:
  o Microsoft Visual Studio 2012* Standard Edition (or higher edition) with C++
component installed
  o Microsoft Visual Studio 2010* Standard Edition (or higher edition) with C++ and
“X64 Compiler and Tools” components installed [1]
  o Microsoft Visual Studio 2008* Standard Edition (or higher edition) with C++ and
“X64 Compiler and Tools” components installed [1]

To use command-line tools only to build IA-32 architecture applications, one of:
  o Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2012 for Windows Desktop*
Intel® C++ Composer XE 2013 for Windows*
Installation Guide and Release Notes 5
  o Microsoft Visual C++ 2010* Express Edition
  o Microsoft Visual C++ 2008* Express Edition

To use command-line tools only to build Intel® 64 architecture applications:
  o Microsoft Windows Software Development Kit Update for Windows 7* and .NET
Framework 4*
```

So if you want to use it without a paid for version of VS it seems you are limited to command line compilation and VS Express.

The compiler is available for Linux though if that is an alternative.

Edit: the notes also says this:

> Command-line development can be done with Visual Studio 2012 Express
>   Edition. Unlike earlier versions, Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition
>   supports both 32-bit and 64-bit commandline development, so no other
>   Platform SDK should be necessary for 64-bit development.

Comment: Thanks @jpw.  Command line only is fine with me.  It's been vim + makefiles for me since the '90s anyway. :)